# how to set best size of Imageview for the different sized images in Listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am developing an `android app`. What I am trying to do is a `listview` with custom view having some text and an images. The images I am downloading from internet have different size. And I want to resize them without changing their appearance. If I set `ImageView` `height` and  `weight` in xml file, my app will have same appearance on different screen size devices. If I set `ImageView` layout size to `wrap content`, images looks terrible in app because they each of them have different size. An idea or tutorial would be nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you would want to do is resize the images in something like gimp or photoshop, and save multiple copies of the images at different sizes.

You'll want to look up [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: As I said in my question, my app receives images from internet with the query of user. I think what you suggest is not reasonable for my problem. Thanks any way

Answer (score 0):

The [scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) attribute of ImageView is very useful in fixing resizing issues on different screen sizes. [This site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) has sample images of all scaleTypes.

One solution is to use a sufficiently large image, specify match_parent as the layout_width of the ImageView, and use an exact layout_height in dp. If scaleType is centerCrop, the image's dimension is maintained [although only a part of the image may be shown, depending on the screen size].